# How to select a radio button with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

HTML:

```html
<input id="rbtn50" type="radio" name="rbtn50" value="rbtn50" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'rbtn50\',\'\')', 0)">
```

Current radio button at

```html
<input id="rbtn20" type="radio" name="rbtn20" value="rbtn20" checked="checked">
```

Attempt 1:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "rbtn50")))
button.click()
```

Attempt 1:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'rbtn50')
button.click()
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="rbtn50"]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an xpath for it

```py
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rbtn50']")
button.click()
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I got the same "NosuchElementException" error.

Comment: Could you give a sample for the code block?  I took your example code and it seemed to work locally with the following html:

`<fieldset>
    <legend>Select a maintenance drone:</legend>
    <input id="rbtn50" type="radio" name="rbtn50" value="rbtn50" onclick="alert('clicked');" >
    <input id="rbtn20" type="radio" name="rbtn20" value="rbtn20" checked="checked">
</fieldset>`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this element was loaded inside an iframe element, maybe the xpath from the element that you want is being searched in the outerMost parent element, but the Xpath is in fact inside the element of the second html.

Solution, use:

```
wdriver.switch_to.frame('id_of_the_iframe_you_want_to_inspect')
```

If this is the case:
This function switches the focus to a specific frame. you can pass other parameters to identify the iframe you must target to SELENIUM to inspect and find your element.

If your element is inside the iframe, find_element won't work until you switch the focus of it.